# How to create an image sequence from a video using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to create an image sequence from a video that is 1 frame per minute. I am using the code:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -r n output_%03d.png
```

When I want 1 frame per minute i put 0.0166666666666667 (1/60) for "n" but it does not come out accurate, and repeats the first two frames. is there a better way to do this?

I am using Windows.

This is as much as it allows me to copy.

> Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (fdsc / 0x63736466), 21 kb/s (default)
>       Metadata:
>         creation_time   : 2015-01-09T12:34:12.000000Z
>         handler_name    :         GoPro SOS
>   [swscaler @ 0000000001c38220] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did se
>   t range correctly
>   [image2 @ 0000000002343020] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to mux
>   ers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
>   Output #0, image2, to 'output_%03d.png':
>     Metadata:
>       major_brand     : mp41
>       minor_version   : 538120216
>       compatible_brands: mp41
>       encoder         : Lavf57.48.103
>       Stream #0:0(eng): Video: png, rgb24, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 20
>   0 kb/s, 0.02 fps, 0.02 tbn, 0.02 tbc (default)
>       Metadata:
>         creation_time   : 2015-01-09T12:34:12.000000Z
>         handler_name    :         GoPro AVC
>         encoder         : Lavc57.55.101 png
>   Stream mapping:
>     Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> png (native))
>   Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
>   frame=    2 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=118 s
>   frame=    2 fps=2.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=259 s
>   frame=    2 fps=1.3 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=407 s
>   frame=    2 fps=1.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=538 s
>   frame=    2 fps=0.8 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=688 s
>   frame=    2 fps=0.6 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=838 s
>   frame=    2 fps=0.6 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=979 s
>   frame=    2 fps=0.5 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1123
>   frame=    2 fps=0.4 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1258
>   frame=    2 fps=0.4 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1406
>   frame=    2 fps=0.4 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1551
>   frame=    2 fps=0.3 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1678
>   frame=    2 fps=0.3 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1825
>   frame=    2 fps=0.3 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1969
>   frame=    2 fps=0.3 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2102
>   frame=    2 fps=0.2 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2242
>   frame=    2 fps=0.2 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2385
>   frame=    2 fps=0.2 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2518
>   frame=    2 fps=0.2 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2671
>   frame=    2 fps=0.2 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2814
>   frame=    2 fps=0.2 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2946
>   frame=    2 fps=0.2 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3090
>   frame=    2 fps=0.2 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3238
>   frame=    2 fps=0.2 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3384
>   frame=    2 fps=0.2 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3529
>   frame=    2 fps=0.2 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3658
>   frame=    2 fps=0.1 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3810
>   frame=    2 fps=0.1 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3958
>   frame=    2 fps=0.1 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=4107
>   frame=    2 fps=0.1 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=4258
>   frame=    2 fps=0.1 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=4401
>   frame=    2 fps=0.1 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=4549
>   frame=    2 fps=0.1 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=4678
>   frame=    2 fps=0.1 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=4829
>   frame=    2 fps=0.1 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=4975
>   frame=    2 fps=0.1 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=5107
>   frame=    2 fps=0.1 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=5243
>   frame=    2 fps=0.1 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=5389
>   frame=    2 fps=0.1 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=5518
>   frame=    2 fps=0.1 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=5668
>   frame=    2 fps=0.1 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=5818
>   frame=    2 fps=0.1 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=5971
>   frame=    2 fps=0.1 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=6093
>   frame=    2 fps=0.1 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=6238
>   frame=    2 fps=0.1 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=6385
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=6513
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=6653
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=6777
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=6925
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=7067
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=7202
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=7341
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=7480
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=7600
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=7689
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=7795
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=7911
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=7984
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=8077
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=8186
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=8329
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=8457
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=8601
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=8733
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=8840
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=8964
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=9061
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=9173
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=9283
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=9405
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=9536
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=9657
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=9777
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=9829
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=9911
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1000
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1011
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1021
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1031
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1043
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1055
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1067
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1079
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1091
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1105
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1119
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1133
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1145
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1159
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1173
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1187
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1199
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1211
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1223
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1234
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1247
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1259
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1273
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1285
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1300
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1313
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1328
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1343
>   frame=    3 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1356
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1368
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1381
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1395
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1409
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1424
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1438
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1452
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1466
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1480
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1493
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1506
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1520
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1535
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1549
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1564
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1578
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1592
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1606
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1619
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1634
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1649
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1661
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1676
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1691
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1705
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1720
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1733
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1746
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1761
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1775
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1790
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1805
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1820
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1835
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1849
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1863
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1877
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1892
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1907
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1921
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1936
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1949
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1964
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1978
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1992
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2006
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2021
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2036
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2051
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2066
>   frame=    4 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:02:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2081
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2095
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2110
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2123
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2138
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2153
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2169
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2183
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2197
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2213
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2224
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2237
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2252
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2267
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2279
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2292
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2307
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2321
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2336
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2351
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2364
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2379
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2392
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2405
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2418
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2433
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2447
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2462
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2477
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2492
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2506
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2520
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2534
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2549
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2562
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2577
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2591
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2606
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2621
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2636
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2650
>   frame=    5 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2664
>   frame=    5 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2678
>   frame=    5 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2685
>   frame=    5 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2693
>   frame=    5 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2704
>   frame=    5 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2717
>   frame=    5 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2730
>   frame=    5 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2745
>   frame=    5 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2759
>   frame=    5 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2771
>   frame=    5 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2784
>   frame=    5 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:03:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2799
>   frame=    6 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2813
>   frame=    6 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2826
>   frame=    6 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2839
>   frame=    6 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2853
>   frame=    6 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2864
>   frame=    6 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2869
>   frame=    6 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2879
>   frame=    6 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2886
>   frame=    6 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2897
>   frame=    6 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2906
>   frame=    6 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2917
>   frame=    6 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2928
>   frame=    6 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2940
>   frame=    6 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2952
>   frame=    6 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2963
>   frame=    6 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2975
>   frame=    6 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=2989
>   frame=    6 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3004
>   frame=    6 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3016
>   frame=    6 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3029
>   frame=    6 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3042
>   frame=    6 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3057
>   frame=    6 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3068
>   frame=    6 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3078
>   frame=    6 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3091
>   frame=    6 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3105
>   frame=    6 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3119
>   frame=    6 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3131
>   frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3146
>   frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3161
>   frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3174
>   frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3189
>   frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3200
>   frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3214
>   frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3228
>   frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3242
>   frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3255
>   frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3269
>   frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3284
>   frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3299
>   frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3311
>   frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3326
>   frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3341
>   frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3355
>   frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3370
>   frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3384
>   frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3399
>   frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3413
>   frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3427
>   frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3442
>   frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3455
>   frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3468
>   frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3482
>   frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3496
>   frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:04:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3509
>   frame=    7 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:05:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3524
>   frame=    7 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:05:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3538
>   frame=    7 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:05:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3551
>   frame=    7 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:05:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3564
>   frame=    7 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:05:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3579
>   frame=    7 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:05:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=3593
>   frame=    7 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:07:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=359
>   82 speed=3.08x
>   video:9195kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing
>   overhead: unknown

Comment: Share the full console output.

Comment: Run the command with `-report`. Paste the contents of the text file generated.